# Даны значения двух моментов времени, принадлежащих одним и тем же суткам

Tags: python, время, datetime

Даны значения двух моментов времени, принадлежащих одним и тем же суткам: часы, минуты и секунды для каждого из моментов времени. Второй момент времени наступил не раньше первого. Определите, сколько часов, минут и секунд прошло между двумя моментами времени.
Программа на вход получает две строки данных: часы, минуты, секунды разделенные двоеточием, задающие первый и второй моменты времени.
Выведите число часов, минут и секунд между этими моментами времени в одной строке через пробел.

Sample Input:

```
11:28:47
22:12:2
```

Sample Output:

```
10 43 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно основная идея - преобразовать в секунды, а потом обратно. Можно рассматривать время как запись числа в системе счисления с основанием 60

```
t1=list(map(int,input().split(':')))
t2=list(map(int,input().split(':')))

s1=t1[0]*3600+t1[1]*60+t1[2]
s2=t2[0]*3600+t2[1]*60+t2[2]

interval=s2-s1

hour=interval // 3600
interval = interval %3600
minute = interval // 60
second = interval %60

print(hour, minute, second)
```

Comment: можно воспользоваться `divmod()`: `hour, interval = divmod(interval, 3600); minute, second = divmod(interval, 60)`

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = "11:28:47"
t2 = "22:12:2"
res = datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
print(res)
```

получим:

```
10:43:15
```

**UPDATE:**

чтобы вывести без двоеточий:

```
res = str(datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")).replace(':',' ')
```

Получим:

```
10 43 15
```

Comment: Вывод без двоеточий требуется.

Comment: Подскажите как продолжить вот тут  чтобы ответ был 10 43 15

Comment: @K449`print(res.replace(":"," "))`

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica это же объект типа datetime, так не выйдет. Там нужно присвоить тип str, а только потом выводить

Comment: @Fox_Hastin обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Или можно так

```
import datetime

one_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=11, minutes=28, seconds=47)
another_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=22, minutes=12, seconds=2)
print(str(another_time-one_time).replace(':', " ")) #10 43 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Прошлый вариант хороший, но можно сделать проще с timedelta из библиотеки datetime.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
firstTime = list(map(int, input().split(':')))
secondTime = list(map(int, input().split(':')))
print(' '.join((str(timedelta(hours=secondTime[0], minutes=secondTime[1], seconds=secondTime[2]) - timedelta(hours=firstTime[0], minutes=firstTime[1], seconds=firstTime[2])).split(':'))))
```

Если не обязателей такой вывод, то можно выводить проще.

```py
print(timedelta(hours=secondTime[0], minutes=secondTime[1], seconds=secondTime[2]) - timedelta(hours=firstTime[0], minutes=firstTime[1], seconds=firstTime[2]))
```